# After update from Jenkins 1.3.x to Jenkins 1.44 the jobs could not found any more

Tags: tomcat, continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins

After I did the update (just replaced the .war and deleted the unzipped folder in tomcat) I could not see the jobs any more. They are still on the file system in the right place. If I create a new test-job the job folder is correctly created next to the jobs that are not displayed any more.

In the tomcat log I could find a hint:

```
04.01.2012 15:38:53 jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onTaskFailed
SCHWERWIEGEND: Failed Loading job XXX
hudson.util.IOException2: Unable to read /var/lib/tomcat5.5/hudson/jobs/XXX/config.xml
    at hudson.XmlFile.read(XmlFile.java:137)
    at hudson.model.Items.load(Items.java:114)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$14.run(Jenkins.java:2360)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:146)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:259)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:800)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:187)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:94)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Whats going wrong?
Thanks!

EDIT:
I guess I messed up my jobs, while I accidently installed a hudson version during the update. The way I fixed it: restore the backup...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds strange. Maybe you could use the "Job Import Plugin" to restore your jobs?

[See Here Job Import Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+Import+Plugin)

Answer (score 0):

The version 1.3XXX is called [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org) which has a different location of the jobs (.hudson) whereas the newer versions (1.4..) are called [jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org) which have the location .jenkins...This can be solved by defining the JENKINS_HOME environment variable before starting Jenkins to use the old location..